# Como recuperar o estado de um botão com SharedPreferences em Android/Kotlin em múltiplas telas?

Tags: android-activity, sharedpreferences, persistência, kotlin

Amigos, tenho duas activitys, na primeira tenho um botão de som ligado e desligado e na segunda tenho alguns botões como por exemplo um botão de nome A e quando clicado ele deve saber qual o estado do botão de som que fica na primeira activity... se na primeira activity o botão de desligar e ligar estiver em estado ligado o botão A deve fazer o som ou o contrário quando estiver em estado de desligado. 
Acontece que há alguns dias tenho tentado e ainda não consegui solucionar. O que vocês me dizem? aguardo alguma posição.

**Primeira tela**

Esse método fica na primeira tela onde salvo o preferences, ou pelo menos achei que salvava...

[[image: Primeira tela[1]]

```
   open fun toChangeButtonVolume() {


    volume_play_menu.setOnClickListener({


        v -> v.isSelected = !v.isSelected

        if (v.isSelected) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_ligado)
            val prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val ed = prefs.edit()

            ed.putInt("chave", 1)

            ed.commit()
        }

        else {

            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_mudo)
        }
    })
```

**Segunda tela**
Este método fica na segunda tela quando tento recuperar o preferences criado na primeira tela. O botão de nome **abc_aprender_a** deve emitir som dependendo do estado do botão criado na primeira activity.

fun goFirstLetter( ) {

```
    abc_aprender_a.setOnClickListener({

        v ->
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check)

        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        //Imagino que aqui eu consiga recuperar a chave na primeira tela ou deveria pelo menos 

        val boo = prefs.getInt("chave", 1)
         playSoundInButton()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (v.isSelected) {
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_ligado)
} else {
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_mudo)
}

val prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val ed = prefs.edit()
ed.putBoolean("chave", v.isSelected)
ed.commit()

abc_aprender_a.setOnClickListener({  v ->
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check)
   val prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   val boo = prefs.getBoolean("chave", true)
   if(boo){
       playSoundInButton()
   }
}
```

Comment: Tenta assim, deve fucionar  :D

Comment: Outra opção é a de passar via Intent o estado do botão (mudo ou não mudo)